# python replace 0 with blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe for which i need a spaceific set of rows and columns as blank always.

I am using the below for row 2, 3, 4 and column from 19:37 but its not working. Below code does not give an error but does not replace the 0 with blank.

```
df_return_3.iloc[2:5, 19:37].replace('^0.0$', '')
```

```
df_return_3.iloc[2:5, 19:37].str.replace('^0.0$', '')
```

This one gives an error: "**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'**"

It would also be ok if i can replace this range of dataframe without checking what value is present before replace.

Comment: You need to set it equal to itself for the change to be implemented. `df_return_3.iloc[2:5, 19:37] = df_return_3.iloc[2:5, 19:37].replace('^0.0$', '')`

Comment: not sure why but it doesnt work. I tried it with ```inplace=True``` also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just replacing 0 with blank, this should work unless I'm missing something:

```
df_return_3.iloc[2:5, 19:37] = df_return_3.iloc[2:5, 19:37].astype(str).replace('0*', '', regex=True)
```